# LEFT JOIN not keeping only records that occur in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following SQL select statement that I use to get a subset of products, or wines:

```
SELECT pv.SkProdVariantId AS id,
       pa.Colour AS colour,
  FROM Dim.ProductVariant AS pv
  JOIN ProductAttributes_new AS pa
    ON pv.SkProdVariantId = pa.SkProdVariantId
 WHERE pv.ProdTypeName = 'Wines'
```

The length of this table generated is 3,905. I want to get all the transactional data for these products.
At the moment I'm using this select statement

```
SELECT c.CalDate AS timestamp,
       f.SkProductVariantId AS sku_id,
       f.Quantity AS quantity
  FROM fact.FTransactions AS f
LEFT JOIN Dim.Calendar AS c
          ON f.SkDateId = c.SkDateId
LEFT JOIN (    
  SELECT pv.SkProdVariantId AS id,
         pa.Colour AS colour,
    FROM Dim.ProductVariant AS pv
    JOIN ProductAttributes_new AS pa
      ON pv.SkProdVariantId = pa.SkProdVariantId
   WHERE pv.ProdTypeName = 'Wines'  
  ) AS s
  ON s.id = f.SkProductVariantId
 WHERE c.CalDate LIKE '%2019%'
```

The calendar dates are correct, but the number of **unique** products returned is 5,648, rather than the expected 3,905 from the select query.

Why does my `LEFT JOIN` on the first select query not work as I expect it to, please?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A left join will duplicate rows if the number of matching rows in the join is > 1

Comment: @Charlieface That's what I'd expect as there could be many transactions associated to one product. However, what I'm seeing is there are more unique SKU IDs in the second table that there are in the first which must be incorrect?

Comment: You are selecting all transactions in 2019. `LEFT JOIN Dim.Calendar` is really an `INNER JOIN Dim.Calendar`, because with `WHERE c.CalDate LIKE '%2019%'` you dismiss all outer joined rows (if there exist any, which I doubt). You then outer join wine info. In the result you'll have all transactions of 2019 and the winy ones will have the additinal wine info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the rows form your query, it needs to be the *first* reference in the `LEFT JOIN`.  Then, I am guessing that you want transaction in 2019:

```
select . . .
from (SELECT pv.SkProdVariantId AS id, pa.Colour AS colour,
      FROM Dim.ProductVariant pv JOIN
           ProductAttributes_new pa
           ON pv.SkProdVariantId = pa.SkProdVariantId
      WHERE pv.ProdTypeName = 'Wines'
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     (fact.FTransactions f JOIN
      Dim.Calendar c
      ON f.SkDateId = c.SkDateId AND
         c.CalDate >= '2019-01-01' AND
         c.CalDate < '2020-01-01'
     )
     ON s.id = f.SkProductVariantId;
```

Note that this assumes that `CalDate` is really a date and not a string.  `LIKE` should only be used on strings.

Comment: That must be where I'm going wrong, I'll give it a go ASAP ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand somehow how outer joins work. See Gordon's answer and my request comment on that.

As to the task: It seems you want to select transactions of 2019, but you want to restrict your results to wine products. We typically restrict query results in the `WHERE` clause. You can use `IN` or `EXISTS` for that.

```
SELECT
  c.CalDate AS timestamp,
  f.SkProductVariantId AS sku_id,
  f.Quantity AS quantity
FROM fact.FTransactions AS f
INNER JOIN Dim.Calendar AS c ON f.SkDateId = c.SkDateId
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, c.CalDate) = 2019
AND f.SkProductVariantId IN
(
  SELECT pv.SkProdVariantId
  FROM Dim.ProductVariant AS pv
  WHERE pv.ProdTypeName = 'Wines'
);
```

(I've removed the join to ProductAttributes_new, because it doesn't seem to play any part in this query.)

Comment: Thanks for your help and clearing up a few points.